# REACT: How do i change the rendered JSX on my test site?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to learn React and currently I'm testing around with my personal website.

The question is i don't really know how to make my site render a new JSX.
In pure HTML i just use a link on a button then link it to my second HTML file.
I'm trying to do this with this.setState and with handleClick().
I will post the relevant code.

Can someone explain this and or give me a solution? I have been stuck at this the whole day!

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import Explore from './Components/Explore';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


export class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCick = this.handleCick.bind(this);
    this.state = { page: <App onClick={this.handleClick}/> }
  }
  handleCick() {
    this.setState({ page: <Explore /> })
  }
  render () {
    return this.state.page
  }
}




 const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Home />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <div className="pb" alt="Profile picture"></div>
          <h1>Magnus Pladsen</h1>
          <h2>Junior Developer</h2>
          <div className="icons">
            <a href=""><div className="icon facebook"></div></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><div className="icon linkedin"></div></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><div className="icon github"></div></a>
          </div>
            <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Explore</button>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

**Explore.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './Explore.css';



class Explore extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Explore">
              <header className="Explore-header">
                <div className="pb" alt="Profile picture"></div>
                <h1>TEST</h1>
                <h2>THIS CODE WILL CHANGE WHEN I GET IT TO RENDER</h2>
                <div className="icons">
                  <a href="" target="_blank"><div className="icon facebook"></div></a>
                  <a href="" target="_blank"><div className="icon linkedin"></div></a>
                  <a href="" target="_blank"><div className="icon github"></div></a>
                </div>
              </header>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Explore;
```

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: What do you are looking for is `react-router-dom`

Comment: -1 No errors
-2 I tried this but i did not understand it :( Tried for a few hours.
But should my code work or am i far off a solution?

Comment: You should use `this.setState` to update the state probably. You should read some react tutorial

Comment: I am using this in the code, but i dont think its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going about this the wrong way in React. You have a few options.

Id highly reccomend looking at [React Router](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

This is by far the best solution and youll get code similar to below in your `App.js` component.

The docs are easy enough to follow for a basic example.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

// import pages
import Home from './pages/Home'
import Explore from './pages/explore'

function App() {
  return (
   <Router>
     <Switch>
       <Route exact path = "/">
         <Home />
       </Route>
       <Route path = "/explore">
         <About />
       </Route>
     </Switch>
   </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

You could also use [useHistory()](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) which also had easy to follow examples.

If you are just playing around there is also the option of good old vanilla JS.

```js
window.open(<yourpage>)
```